# Simple Data Grading Application Support Needed

Tags: javascript, java

Hello people of stack,

My partner and I have recently wanted to create a simple application as part of a bet in which the application reads a set of peoples names and results from an input TXT file and creates an output TXT file in which the previous inputs grading results are formatted from Highest to Lowest and possibly the highest score from the input TXT file shown at the bottom.

We created a test script which worked for the most part but had some major errors which I was not able to figure out, so I did not include my current script as there was a lit of curves and bends with the scripture.

If anyone could please help me and my partner we would greatly appreciate it and so we can see where we went wrong to learn further about this.

I have attached the core Input File which we had used and I attached a photo of how we'd prefer the outcome TXT file was ordered in.[The image on the left is the desired outcome TXT file, the right one is the core input TXT file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1IcE.png)

Thank you for your help,
Sincerely
- M

EDIT: CODE 1: I implemented a 10 Subject and grade system which was unnecessary but here you go should you need it:

```js
import java.util.Scanner;

public class UserInteraction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int choice = 0;
        String[] subjects = new String[10];
        int grades[] = new int[10];
        double sum = 0.0;

    do
    {
        System.out.println("1. Enter a course name and a grade");
        System.out.println("2. Display all grades");
        System.out.println("3. Calculate the average grade");
        System.out.println("4. Exit program");

        choice = scan.nextInt();

        if ( choice == 1 ) 
        {
            Scanner scansubjects = new Scanner(System.in);
            Scanner scangrades = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Enter 10 subjects and their corresponding grades:");
            System.out.println();

            int i = 0;

            for( i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
            {
                System.out.println("Subject:");

                String temp = scansubjects.nextLine();
                subjects[i] = temp.toLowerCase();

                System.out.println("Grade:");

                grades[i] = scangrades.nextInt();

                if( i == ( subjects.length - 1 ) )
                {
                    System.out.println("Thank you!");
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }


        if ( choice == 2 )
        {
            System.out.println("Subjects" + "\tGrades");
            System.out.println("---------------------");

            for(int p = 0; p < subjects.length; p++)
            {

                System.out.println(subjects[p] + "\t" + "\t" + grades[p]);
            }
        }

        if ( choice == 3 )
        {   
              System.out.println("Total of grades: " + getSum(grades));
              System.out.println("Count of grades: " + grades.length);
              System.out.println("Average of grades: " + getAverage(grades));
              System.out.println();
        }


    } while ( choice != 4);


}

    public static double getAverage(int[] array)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i : array) sum += i;
        return ((double) sum)/array.length;
    }

    public static double getSum(int[] array)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i : array) 
        {
         sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

}
```

CODE 2: Worked but it did not organise the information and nor did it create a new file, it simply copied the first file and placed it into a new file:

```js
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.PrintStream;
public class ReadConsole {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("Out.txt"));
            File file = new File("Data.txt");

            input = new Scanner(file); //scans the file


            while (input.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = input.nextLine();
                output.println(line);
            }
            input.close();

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You have to show us the code and point out where the problem is, and display the errors?

Comment: I don't quite know the problem, I'll put in the codes I've tried and hopefully you could help, theres no error in the first one but I do not know how to make it read and organise the input through the use of array.

Comment: I have placed the code into the post now.